# Android adding and removing to a different ListView using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

This has been driving me insane. I have a `ListView` and a `ArrayList` as my adapter. The `ListView` mode is `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and the layout is `simple_list_item_checked`. I can now select multiple items in my `ListView`.

My situation:

```
    int length = jsonList.size();

    SparseBooleanArray checked = lv_Devices.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i <length ; i++ ){

         if (checked.get(i)) {


             onList.add(jsonList.get(i));

             jsonList.remove(i);
             lv_Devices.setItemChecked(i, false);


             length--;

        }   
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterOn.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
size of array 8 : contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  

you removed index 0  
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  


you removed index 1  
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  


you removed index 2  
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]  


you removed index 3  
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

As you can see from the end result the array is shifting indexes. The goal I am trying to achieve: get each selected item and add them to the other `ListView` while removing from the current `ListView`.

The LogCat shows what happens when I select all the items. This is also happening on a button click. Any advice on this would be perfect. This is also my first time using stackoverflow. I don't really use it much as the majority of programming errors have been discussed on here. I am having difficulty on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int item = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    if (checked.get(i)) {
        onList.add(jsonList.get(item));
        jsonList.remove(item);
        lv_Devices.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
    else {
        item++;
    }
}
```

It will try to remove the first item in the array (item 0). If that item is checked, it will be removed. This means the item that was previously item 1 is now item 0, so it will just check item 0 again.

If, however, item 0 is not checked, it will move on to item 1, and keep doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I just gave this a shot and now it moves 1 , 3 , 5 , 7 and skips 2 , 4 , 6 , 8

Comment: @Rachel Which items are ticked?

Comment: all of them =S this is why I am so confused

Comment: Also if this is any help, if i select only 1 and 2 to be moved, it moved 1 and 3

Comment: I think I realise what I've done-- I've just updated the code. Could you try that for me and let me know if it works?

Comment: Omg thank you so so much it works perfectly how the :@ amazing it works for one selection and multiple. I have been on this practically all day using booleans and setting the i to start back at 0 but no matter what I done it was mind boggling. I have never had to work with shifting array indexes absolutely Amazing really great = ) It seemed to me one of them gotcha moments which can puzzle you for the whole day! quick and fast response @user184994

Comment: No probs, glad I could help